# react-multi-select-component is not working as expected in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, npm, internet-explorer-11, multi-select

Below is the sample code, This sample working fine in all other browsers, except IE11. This dropdown closes immediately once after it clicked. The dropdown list does not show up.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
const Example: React.FC = () => {
const options = [{ label:"grpes", value: "grapes" },{  label:"mango",value: "mango" }];
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
return (
    <div>
      <h1>Select Fruits</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
<MultiSelect
        options={options}
        value={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
      />
 </div>
  );
};
 
export default Example;
```

Comment: Hi shantih.antony, Welcome to Stackoverflow. can please share the rest of your code?

Comment: I've updated the code as required

Comment: @Alireza please check the updated code

Comment: Couldn't figure out the problem from top of my head. Seems issue with package also searched but didn't find anything that might solve your issue. sorry.

Comment: no prob, thanks for looking in to this

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in IE 11. I found a [similar thread](https://github.com/harshzalavadiya/react-multi-select-component/issues/26) in github. It says lacking of css variables support in IE makes the styles not being rendered properly in IE and it can be fixed by adding polyfill. I tried to add the polyfill he mentioned in the thread but stll can't make it to work in IE. You can also try to add the polyfill to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I've also added polyfill  and tried but still it did not work

Comment: I think the component is not compatible with IE. The author also says there's no plan to directly support IE in this component.

Comment: Thank you, I've replaced this component with 'ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes' and its compatible with all the browsers.

Comment: Great! You can also put your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `react-multi-select-component` dropdown is not compatible with `IE` I've used the below dropdown which has similar features as `react-multi-select-component`.

Component name : `react-multiselect-checkboxes`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiselect-checkboxes